# How to receive data from a button in a form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This seems very simple but I can't figure it out.  I am trying to get back the value of a button so I can conditionally render a page template.  I can't seem to capture the value of the button though.
Here is my js code.

```
app.get("/trades", (req, res) => {  // line 465
 let button_value = req.params.value;
  console.log(button_value);


  // res.render("activate_pause")
});
```

And here is my html/ejs markup:

```
<form action="/trades" methods="get, post" name="groups_button">
    <button class="orange" type="submit" name="frontpage_trades_button" value="pause">Pause Campaigns</button>
    <button type="submit" name="frontpage_trades_button" value="enable">Activate Campaigns</button>
</form>
```

The values 'pause' or 'enable' will be used to set a status of true or false, which will render the desired template ( or so I hope!).  Can anyone help??

Comment: What exactly is the error? What gets logged into the console?

Comment: I just keep getting undefined. I've tried req.body,value as well.

Comment: What is this form? It doesn't have any input?

Comment: It just has the two buttons.  I thought when the button was submitted I could capture the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`methods` is not a valid attribute of the `<form>` element

```js
console.log('Is method in <form>?: ', 'method' in HTMLFormElement.prototype);
console.log('Is methods in <form>?: ', 'methods' in HTMLFormElement.prototype);
```

So the first thing to do is to replace `methods` with `method` and set only one method (I'd suggest `POST`).

Then in the Node.js code, make sure you have the proper middleware in order to decode URL encoded forms:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This should allow you to retrieve the value of the clicked button, like this:

```
app.post("/trades", (req, res) => { 
 let button_value = req.body.frontpage_trades_button;
  console.log(button_value);


  // res.render("activate_pause")
});
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

u can use data attribute to take it

```
 <button type="submit"id="x" name="frontpage_trades_button" data-value="enable">Activate Campaigns</button>

app.get("/trades", (req, res) => {  // line 465
 let button_value = req.params.value;
  console.log($("#x").data("value"));


  // res.render("activate_pause")
});
```

Comment: I tried this but am getting an error due to "$ is not defined".  I checked for jQuery in the console and it is loaded.  Do I need to configure it somehow?  You'll have to excuse my ignorance, I'm still pretty new to programming.